# How can I get a irreducible polynomial of degree 8 over $Z_2[X]$?

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I have got one of degree 5: $x^5+x^2+1$, but I need one of degree 8.

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for displaying functions and exponents.

Comment: Can you add more on how much you know about irreducible polynomials so far? This seems too short for a question.

Comment: AFAIK there are no means substantially better than trial-and-error for small degrees.  You know your constant coefficient must be 1 (else your polynomial is divisible by $x$) and you know you must have an odd number of terms (else it's divisible by $x+1$ - why?); beyond that, just try terms of the form $x^8+x^d+1$ for $1\leq d\lt 8$, and if none of those work then terms of the form $x^8+x^a+x^b+x^c+1$..  Or you could look up "tables of primitive polynomials" and likely find one that way.

Comment: I agree the question is not precise enough. What for do you need it? If you really just need one there are plenty of lists floating around in the internet.

Comment: I have used the trial-and-error and I have found one. @quid: I only need one, but I haven't found any list with polynomial of degree 8 in the internet... Probably I haven't looked for it in the right way, It's hard to me the english in the mathematic subjects.

Comment: Search for irreducible binary polynomial. For a specific example take $x^8 + x^4+x^3 +x+1$. Using the data at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreduciblePolynomial.html  you can check if it is true, say try division by all degree 2,3,4 polynomials.

Comment: Whenever I need a new degree covered, I look up one from [this table](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/papers/CS-07-593/primitive-polynomial-table.txt). The polynomials there are *primitive* in addition to being irreducible. Meaning that any one of their zeros will generate the multiplicative group of the splitting field.

Comment: You can use the fact that $\Bbb{F}_{256}$ is the smallest field with a 17th root of unity $\alpha$. So $(x^{17}-1)/(x-1)$ splits into a product of two irreducible octic polynomials $p_1(x)$ and $p_2(x)$. Furthermore, $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{16}=\alpha^{-1}$ share the same minimal polynomial, so both $p_1$ and $p_2$ are palindromes. This cuts down the number of unknowns, and leads to calculations like in Thomas' (+1) answer. I didn't test whether the complexity becomes manageable. If the question is reopened, I might give it a try :-)

Comment: Yeah. Factoring $p(x)=(x^{17}-1)/(x-1)$ turned out to be easy to do by hand. At least with my arsenal of finite field tricks. It turns out that in addition to the above palindromicity trick you only need basic properties of the trace function. The answer is
$$p(x)=(x^8+x^5+x^4+x^3+1)(x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^2+x+1).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know is trial and error. A polynomial of degree $8$ is irreducible/prime over $\mathbb Z_2$ if it divides:

$$\frac{x^{2^8}-x}{x^{2^4}-x}=\frac{x^{255}-1}{x^{15}-1} = 1+x^{15}+x^{30}+\cdots x^{225}+x^{240}$$

This polynomial is exactly the product of all the prime polynomials of degree $8$, once each.

It's probably easier to use repeated squaring to prove that $p(x)$ divides $x^{256}-x$ and not $x^{16}-x$.

This means there are $30$ such polynomials. Since we want an eighth-degree polynomial, and it is not divisible by $x$ or $x-1=x+1$, this means:

$$p(x)=1+\cdots + x^8$$ where the number of terms in $\cdots$ is odd. So there are $\frac{2^7}{2}=64$ subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,7\}$ that are odd, and therefore, if you chose your $p(x)$ at random under these conditions, you'd get approximately $50\%$ chance of finding a prime each trial.

You can remove the cases where the subset of $\{1,\dots,7\}$ are only even. For example, we know:
$$1+x^4+x^6+x^8 = (1+x^2+x^3+x^4)^2$$
That process removes $4$ of the $64$ bad options, and now we have exactly a $50\%$ chance.

We can also avoid duplicate testing by not testing reflections. Assuming $a_0=a_8=1$, then $\sum_0^8 a_ix^i$ is irreducible if and only if $\sum_{0}^8 a_{8-i}x^i$ is irreducible.

So if you've eliminated $1+x+x^8$, you've eliminated $1+x^7+x^8$, for example.

That doesn't reduce our options quite in half, because some polynomials are self-reflective. (And it doesn't increase our initial odds of finding a prime on the first try.)

This still requires trial and error.

Example trial for $p(x)=1+x+x^8$. Then:

$$x^{8}\equiv 1+x\pmod{p(x)}\\
x^{16}\equiv 1+x^2\pmod{p(x)}$$
So $x^{16}-x$ is not divisible by $p(x)$.
$$x^{32}\equiv 1+x^4\pmod{p(x)}\\
x^{64}\equiv 1+x^8\equiv  x\pmod{p(x)}\\
x^{128}\equiv x^2\pmod{p(x)}\\
x^{256}\equiv x^4\pmod{p(x)}$$

We could actually stop at $x^{64}$, since it means that $p(x)$ divides $x^{2^6}-x$, which means it must be the product of primes of degree $1,2,3,$ and $6$. Since it is not divisible by a linear polynomial it must be divisible by the only prime of degree $2$, $q(x)=1+x+x^2$. Since $(1+x+x^2)(1+x)=x^3+1$, we get that:

$$p(x)\equiv 1+x+x^5\equiv 1+x+x^2\pmod{1+x+x^2}$$ Indeed, this gives us another way to ensure that $p(x)$ is not prime: $1+x+x^2$ divides $\sum a_ix^i$ with $\sum a_i=1$ and $a_0=a_8=1$ if $$a_3+a_6=0, a_1+a_4+a_7=1\\a_2+a_5=0$$

We get that $1+x^3+x^8$ is divisible by $1+x+x^3$.

I get that $1+x+x^2+x^4+x^8$ is prime, but I'd want to check this.

Another way to check, by the way, is to ensure that $p(x)$ is relatively prime to $x^{8}-x$ (and thus not divisible by any prime of degree $3$) and relatively prime to $x^{16}-x$, and thus not divisible by any prime of degree $1,2,4$.

I get that $1+x+x^3+x^4+x^8$ is irreducible, but I did it on paper, so I'd want to check.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's very instructive for me :-)

Comment: $1+x+x^2+x^4+x^8=(1+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$, so hopefully that line was a typo for the polynomial in the last line, which is irreducible.